# How to create multiple filter query in solr?

Tags: solr

I want to create query that can search on my pdf and text document. i can create the single query for content_type but for both at the same time i don't know how fix it,
for example for searching on my pdf document i create :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/file/select?q=*&fq=content_type:application/pdf
```

but for text/plain and application/pdf i create bellow queries but do not work:

```
q=flex&fq=content_type:application/pdf&text/plain
q=flex&fq=content_type:application/pdf&fq=content_type:text/plain
```

Answer (score 4):

Try: fq=content_type:application/pdf OR content_type:text/plain

Comment: You should have parentheses around the list of OR values. Something like fieldname:(val1 OR val2 OR val3).

Comment: What if you need to add filter queries for two different fields?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax ought to be:

http://localhost:8983/solr/file/select?q=flex&fq=content_type:(application/pdf OR text/plain)